# How to use WNS in windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8, push-notification, mpns

I have a application that has a mobile client and a Windows 8 client. I want to implement push notification service between two app.

I found that windows 8 use WNS (windows Notification Service) and windows Phone 8 use MPNS (Microsoft Push Notification Service) for push notification service and they are two different server.

Is there any way to use WNS from windows Phone 8?

Or any way to achieve this?

any advice or any tutorial are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No wns is only working for win8. You can look into notification hub from azure.

You cannot send it directly as far as I know. You have to go through a server and again have a look at azure.

Answer (score 0):

WNS is supported on Windows Phone as of Windows Phone 8.1. If you're building an app for both Windows 8 and Windows Phone, you should use WNS.

It is not possible to use WNS on Windows Phone 8.0, but WP8.1 is a free upgrade for your users.